# Equivalence relation of sub-groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $H_{1},H_{2}<G$. $H_{1}\sim H_{2}$ iff $\left[H_{1}:H_{1}\cap H_{2}\right]<\infty,\left[H_{2}:H_{1}\cap H_{2}\right]<\infty$.
I need your help proving the transitivity of $\sim$.
I tried to use standard index properties.. didn't work. I prefer an hint first. Thank you !

Comment: Assume $H_1 \sim H_2$ and $H_2 \sim H_3$. Then $|H_2 :H_1 \cap H_2|$ finite implies $|H_2 \cap H_3: H_1 \cap H_2 \cap H_3|$ implies $|H_3:H_1 \cap H_2 \cap H_3|$ finite.